# error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’ on line 8

Tags: c++, c++11

I keep on getting this error, and I don't know why.Please won't someone explain why such a error is and how I can avoid such a error. This is being compiled with g++

**My header file**

```
#ifndef  _STUDENT_H 
#define  _STUDENT_H 
#include <string>
namespace name {
   class StudentRecord
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string surname;
    std::string studentNumber;
    std::string classRecord;
    int token;

public:
    StudentRecord(std::string  n , std::string s , std::string x , std::string c );
    StudentRecord(void);
    StudentRecord(const StudentRecord & rhs);

    StudentRecord(StudentRecord && rhs );
    ~StudentRecord();
    int avg(void);
    int aquire_token(void);
    void release_token(void);
};

}
#endif
```

**My cpp file as stands **

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "studentrecords.h"
namespace name{


// Copy Constructor
    // Error
StudentRecord(const StudentRecord & rhs)
{};

// Move Constructor




}
```

Comment: Errors come with line numbers. Point out the line in your posting on which the error occurs.

Comment: @KerrekSB Added Line number

Comment: No no no no no. Who knows what "8" means. Point it out **in the code you posted** (e.g. with a comment `// error on this line`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Class name prefix is missing:

```
// Copy Constructor
StudentRecord::StudentRecord(const StudentRecord & rhs)
{}
```

Note also that you don't need `;` after constructor implementation.

Comment: Even though it is in the same namespace?

Comment: @Matthew Yes, there can be multiple classes in a namespace, so you need it to point out which class the method is implemented for.

Comment: @Matthew its a member function so you have to define it using `class_name::member_function_name`. Opening the namespace just means you don't have to write `name::StudentRecord::StudentRecord` instead.

Comment: Yes, of course. Class member implementation can be used without `class_name::` prefix only inside the class definition.

Comment: Also, for better performance, the first constructor should look like `StudentRecord(const std::string&  n , const std::string& s , const std::string& x , const std::string& c)` or even `StudentRecord(const char* n , const char*  s , const char* x , const char* c)`

Comment: @AlexFarber It is always better to pass arguments  by use value by reference ?

Comment: It depends. In your case, if string parameters are not changed in the method, `const ref` allows to prevent unnecessary copying. Writing a class with move constructor, you need to think about another performance issues as well. Specifically for strings, it is better to pass `const char*`, which will be optimal both for `string` instances and string constants.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "studentrecords.h"
namespace name{


// Copy Constructor
StudentRecord::StudentRecord(const StudentRecord & rhs)<----//Change here....
{};

// Move Constructor
}
```